# In what situation (if any) you would say "better play positive"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

In what situation (if any) you would say "better play positive"? Please, don't add any punctuation between words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

> I left after watching the better play positive I would come and see it again.

... or is that cheating?

It's *possible* someone would say

> *You need to win this match, so you'd better play positive!

but to me this sounds a little strange: formal English would have "positively"; "positive" seems a strange choice of words for saying this colloquially, but it wouldn't surprise me too much if someone used this in analogy to the phrase "think positive" which is well-known, or having heard the phrase "positive play". (It's also possible it sounds more natural in the US or in a particular dialect, but someone else will have to comment on that :-)

Comment: If one is to believe the newspapers, using adjectives as adverbs is quite common among sporting people: "we whopped them pretty good".

Answer (score 1):

> Better play positive, negativity wont help you overcome your obstacles.

Here the words, 'better play positive' mean that you better start thinking positively or negativity will not help you solve your problems.

@brilliant- For what situation do you want those words?

Comment: I wasn't after any kind of situation, I just wanted to know if this combination of words would make sense in some kind of setting.